I am calculating Average Rating from interviews table and showing average rating in candidates table. Symfony gives undefined method error
I am calculating Average Rating from interviews table and showing average rating in candidates table. Symfony gives undefined method error
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->leftJoin('c.created_by_name', 'u')
            ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Interviews', 'i', 'WITH', 'c.candidate_id = i.candidate_id')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT AVG(i2.interview_rating) AS averageRating FROM App\Entity\Interviews i2 WHERE i2.candidate_id = c.candidate_id) as average_rating')
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($params["limit"]);

        $qb->addSelect('(SELECT COUNT(ci.candidate_id) FROM App\Entity\CandidatesInvitations ci WHERE ci.candidate_id = c.candidate_id) as applied');

And when I display Paginator item it gives me error getAverageRating undefined
How to resolve this issue as I am stuck and unable to find any solution from documentation

Where is getAverageRating method defined ? Where and how is it called ?

If you want the average_rating to be accessible directly in the Candidate entity, you can add a non-persistent property without Annotation or Attribute @ORM\Column to that entity:
private ?float $averageRating = null;

public function getAverageRating(): ?float
{
    return $this->averageRating;
}

public function setAverageRating(?float $averageRating): void
{
    $this->averageRating = $averageRating;
}

